# OpenLayers 3 popup on marker mouseover

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm only able to get popup on click. Can we get popup on marker mouseover?

Here's the example [link](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/examples/icon.html)

Like in this example popup start display onclick on marker... But I wanted popup will automatically display when I'm moving my cursor over the marker icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example you provided, you can see two events associated with the map object: click and pointermove. If I understood you well, you just have to switch the click event callback function with the pointermove event.